# How can i delete all messages in telegram chat with node js

Tags: telegram-bot

I want to delete all messages in telegram bot chat, without saving their ids to DB.
Telegram bot is written on node-telegram-api

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.